# Sumif with column index instead of alphabet form range

Tags: vba, excel

I am using

```
  =SumIf(ws!A:A,"Some Text", ws!G:G)
```

to add some data to a new spreadsheet.

I am wondering if there is a way to convert A or G to 1 or 7, or some other workaround that will give me the same effect as the Sumif function using column index instead of the alphabetical form.

This seems crucial for me because my next cell will be:

```
sumif(ws!A:A, "Some Text", ws!I:I)
sumif(ws!A:A, "Some Text", ws!K:K)
```

and so on.

I wish to loop this in intervals of two columns (as shown in the example) but I don't know how to do it using the alphabet form of range. Some help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. My intention is to create a macro that will automate this process such that the output of the cells in my new spreadsheet (in one row) is `=SumIf(ws!A:A,"Some Text", ws!G:G)`, followed by `sumif(ws!A:A, "Some Text", ws!I:I)`, followed by `sumif(ws!A:A, "Some Text", ws!K:K)`, all the way till `sumif(ws!A:A, "Some Text", ws!NC:NC)`, without having to type each one individually.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comment realizing that. I was trying to do it without macro though. But since you're going to do it with macro, then it'll be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's using VBA:

```
Sub concious()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer: j = 0 
    For i = 0 To 10 Step 2 '<~~ depends how many columns you wish to populate
        With Sheet2
            Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(0, j).Formula = _
                "=SUMIF(" & .Columns("A:A").Address(, , , True) & _
                ",""Some Text""," & .Columns("G:G").Offset(0, i).Address(, , , True) & ")"
        End With
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Well, `Sheet1` is where you put the formula, `Sheet2` is your reference sheet.
You can replace `Sheet1` with `Sheets("NameofYourActualSheet")` or your actual sheet codename.

This is the formula version:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,"Some Text",OFFSET(Sheet2!$G:$G,,(COLUMN()-1)*2))
```

This part `COLUMN()-1` depends where you want to put your formula.
It works only if formula starts in Column A at Sheet1.

Comment: Thank you for this piece of code, it serves my purpose exactly. :)

Answer (score 1):

edit: edited after realizing OP asked for formula every uneven column...

assuming "NewSheet" as the name of the worksheet you want to add data to via a `SumIf()` function referencing `ws` worksheet, here's two alternative codes

1. "array" approach

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub main()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim myArr As Variant
   Dim i As Long
   Dim formulaStrng As String

   Set ws = Worksheets("OldSheet") '<-- change as per your actual "ws" name
   formulaStrng = "=SumIf(" & ws.Name & "!C1,""Some Text""," & ws.Name & "!C)"
   With Worksheets("NewSheet").Range("A1:NC1")
       ReDim myArr(1 To .Columns.Count)
       For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
           If 2 * Int(i / 2) <> i Then myArr(i) = formulaStrng 
       Next i
       .value = myArr
   End With
   End Sub
   ```
2. "helper row" approach

   ```
   Sub main2()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Worksheets("OldSheet")
   With Worksheets("NewSheet").Range("A1:NC1")
       .FormulaR1C1 = "=SumIf(" & ws.Name & "!C1,""Some Text""," & ws.Name & "!C)"
       With .offset(1) '<--| helper row. assuming row 2 is "free". should it not be, simply adjust the offset
           .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(2*int(column()/2)<>column(),1,"""")" '<-- mark "uneven" columns with "1"
           .value = .value '<-- get rid of formulas
           .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Clear ''<--  clear "even" colums
           .ClearContents ''<-- clear helper row
       End With
   End With

   End Sub
   ```

both approaches can be speeded-up adding the following code at the beginning:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and the the following code by their end:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Answer (score 0):

> =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,x,4),"1","")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,x,4),"1","")

x would be your column

You'd then have to convert that from text to a range:

> =SUMIF(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,x,4),"1","")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,x,4),"1","")),"B",A:A)

Comment: I've not tried it with values larger than integers but its definitely a number yes.